# Как избежать неявное преобразование чисел с плавающей точкой в строку?

Tags: perl

Суть проблемы:

```
perl -MData::Dumper -E 'say Dumper 3'
$VAR1 = 3;

perl -MData::Dumper -E 'say Dumper 3.5'
$VAR1 = '3.5';
```

Как этого избежать?

Comment: Создается ощущение, что никак: http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=909619

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Короткий ответ: не использовать число в том контексте, в котором это преобразование происходит.

Подлинней. В перле нет типов данных "строка" или "число", есть только скаляр. Как именно этот скаляр будет интерпретироваться зависит исключительно от контекста. В данном случае виновник преобразования в строку - сам модуль Data::Dumper, который это делает в своих потрохах. [Data::Printer](https://metacpan.org/pod/Data::Printer), например (который, кстати, на порядок круче), делает наоборот, любую строку, похожую на число, интерпретирует как число:

```
use Data::Printer;
my @data = ( 3, 3.5, '3.5', '3.a' );
p @data;
```

Вывод:

```
[
  [0] 3,
  [1] 3.5,
  [2] 3.5,
  [3] "3.a"
]
```